# Access UINavigationController from classmethod

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, nsobject, class-method

I've a `viewController` called `AudioViewController`. In that, I've this method:

```
- (IBAction)stopAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.audioClass stop];
}
```

I've a `NSObject` class called `AudioClass`. In that, I've these methods:

```
-(void) stop
{
    if (!recorder.recording)
    {
        [player stop];
        player.currentTime = 0;

        [self.recordOrPauseButton setEnabled:YES];
        [self.stopButton setEnabled:NO];

        [self alertMessage];
    }
    else
    {
        [recorder stop];

        AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
        [self alertMessage];
    }
}


-(void) alertMessage
{
    UIAlertView *stopAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done!"
                                                        message: @"Do you want to save it?"
                                                       delegate: self
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancle"
                                              otherButtonTitles:@"Save", nil];
    [stopAlert show];
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        // this is the cancel button
    }
    else
    {
        [self.sqLiteDB insertDataIntoTable:soundFilePath And:outputFileURL];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

Now, here in
`- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger) buttonIndex`
it is not recognizing the
`[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`.
Because, It is in the `NSObject` class. How can I access that `navigationController` and return from `AudioViewControlelr` to it's previous `ViewController`?

If any one have any solution, please share it with me. Thanks a lot in advance. Have a good day.

Comment: can't you just move AlertView logic inside viewController?

Comment: @GonjiDev Thanks for commenting. I can't do that. Because `- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag` this method also using the same `[self alertMessage];` method. Which is in the `AudioClass`.

Comment: Following @CleverError answer you should notify the viewController when `- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag` is called. You can achieve this in various ways, one could be using NSNotificationCenter. Showing Alert is a responsibility of viewControllers.

Comment: @GonjiDev Ok, but It would be easier if I could access a method from `AudioViewController` to `AudioClass`.

Answer (score 1):

iOS development is based on the [Model View Contorller design pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html). Your `AudioViewControlelr` is obviously a controller and your `AudioClass` would actually be a model. In MVC, models should never directly modify views, this includes modifying `UINavigationControllers` and displaying `UIAlertViews`.

In your case, your `AudioViewController` should call stop on the `AudioClass` object and show the `UIAlertView`.

---

On a side note, `AudioRecorder` would be a better name than `AudioClass`. It more accurately describes what the class does, as opposed to just telling us it's a class which we already know.